Using DAX measure to filter pivot to concatenate separate column
I am looking for a way to use a measure to concatenate a column of string values based on a unique value in another column to be displayed on a pivot with its own filtering in place. Below is my most recent attempt, currently returns an error.
I can only use DAX in Excel without using PowerPivot as this needs to be shared with co-workers that will not have that installed.
=VAR Var1 = SELECTCOLUMNS(DISTINCT(Range[Col1]), "UHD", Range[Col2])
  
Return

CONCATENATEX(SUMMARIZE(FILTER(Range, Range[Col2] IN Var1),Range[Col1]),Range[Col1],", ")

I have tried various ways of filtering, but the row context never seems to stick when I grab Col2 to do the concat, and it always outputs without the filter.



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4




5
5a By 9
Yes
Name 1


5
5b By 9
No
Name 1


5
5c By 9
Yes
Name 2


6
6a By 9
Yes
Name 2


6
6b By 9
Yes
Name 2


7
7a By 9
No
Name 3


7
7b By 9
Yes
Name 3


8
8a By 9
No
Name 3



Output Pivot



Col4
Measure Output




Name 1
"5a by 9"


Name 2
"5c by 9, 6b by 9"


Name 3
"7b by 9"



The filter on Col3 can be done in the pivot

Input and expected output please ?

So this is my idea in DAX, but in my opinion I think this kind of requirements should be achieved in Power Query. I will provide the solution in DAX and Power Query.
Using DAX :
Measure Output = 
VAR CurrentName = MAX('Range'[Col4]) 
VAR FilteredRange = FILTER(
    'Range',
    'Range'[Col4] = CurrentName && 'Range'[Col3] = "Yes"
)
VAR SummaryRange = SUMMARIZE(
    FilteredRange,
    'Range'[Col1],
    'Range'[Col4],
    "UniqueConcatCol2", CONCATENATEX(
        DISTINCT(FILTER(FilteredRange, 'Range'[Col1] = EARLIER('Range'[Col1]))),
        'Range'[Col2], ", "
    )
)
RETURN
CONCATENATEX(
    SummaryRange,
    [UniqueConcatCol2],
    ", "
)


Using Power Query :
So first I filtered the data Col3 = Yes :

Then for the Group By, I used Col4 as the column to group by the data :
Then I chose "All Rows" to create a subtable of all rows that share the same Col4.

Then I added new column using Custom Column to the SubTable :

I removed the original Col 4 and then I removed duplicate rows :

